# Controlling read/write access to fields

Tags: c#, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance, access-modifiers

Suppose that we would like to separate out the read and write access in an interface pattern as below.

```
namespace accesspattern
{
    namespace ReadOnly
    {
        public interface IA { double get_a(); }
    }
    namespace Writable
    {
        public interface IA : ReadOnly.IA { void set_a(double value); }
    }
}
```

This is easy to implement:

```
namespace accesspattern
{
    namespace ReadOnly
    {
        public class A : IA
        {
            protected double a;
            public double get_a() { return a; }
        }
    }
    namespace Writable
    {
        public class A : ReadOnly.A, IA
        {
            public void set_a(double value) { base.a = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Suppose that we need another class which inherits from A and so we go ahead and define an interface for it:

```
namespace accesspattern
{
    namespace ReadOnly
    {
        public interface IB : ReadOnly.IA { int get_b(); }

    }
    namespace Writable
    {
        public interface IB : ReadOnly.IB, Writable.IA { void set_b(int value); }
    }
}
```

Implementing this is not so easy. One always feels that Writable.B should inherit from two base classes, Writable.A and ReadOnly.B, to avoid repeated code.

Is there a recommended Design Pattern to use? The aim is to be able to return "read access only" and "read write access" objects separately (decided at compile time) depending on requirements. It would be nice if the solution pattern makes it easy to add more layers of inheritance, classes C, D...

I know that the issue of Multiple Inheritance crops up here and that it has been discussed at length elsewhere in many, many, places. But my question is not so much "How to implement the interfaces which are defined inside the namespace accesspattern without using multiple inheritance" (although I would like to learn the best way to do that) but rather, **how can we define the ReadOnly/Writable versions of a class separately and also support inheritance without it getting very, very, messy**?

For what it is worth here is one (messy) solution [see below for much a better implementation]:

```
    namespace accesspattern
    {
        namespace ReadOnly
        {
            public class A : IA
            {
                protected double a;
                public double get_a() { return a; }
            }
            public class B : IB
            {
                protected int b;
                public int get_b() { return b; }
            }
        }
        namespace Writable
        {
            public class A : ReadOnly.A, IA
            {
                public void set_a(double value) { base.a = value; }
            }
            public class B : ReadOnly.B, IB
            {
                private IA aObj;
                public double get_a() { return aObj.get_a(); }
                public void set_a(double value) { aObj.set_a(value); }
                public void set_b(int value) { base.b = value; }
                public B() { aObj = new A(); }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I think that this (below) is what Eugene is talking about. This implementation pattern is pretty good, I think. By only passing around "writeProtected" views of classes one can implement algorithms which require that the state of the class will not change and only use "writeEnabled" views where it is meant that the function will/could cause a change in state avoiding.

```
namespace access
{

    // usual usage is at least readable
    public interface IA { double get_a(); }
    public interface IB : IA { int get_b(); }

    // special usage is writable as well
    namespace writable
    {
        public interface IA : access.IA { void set_a(double value);  }
        public interface IB : access.IB, IA { void set_b(int value);}
    }

    // Implement the whole of A in one place
    public class A : writable.IA
    {
        private double a;
        public double get_a() { return a; }
        public void set_a(double value) { a = value; }
        public A() { }

        //support write-protection
        public static IA writeProtected() { return new A(); }
        public static writable.IA writable() { return new A(); }
    }
    // implement the whole of B in one place and now no issue with using A as a base class
    public class B : A, writable.IB
    {
        private int b;
        public double get_b() { return b; }
        public void set_b(int value) { b = value; }
        public B() : base() { }

        // support write protection 
        public static IB writeProtected() { return new B(); }
        public static writable.IB writable() { return new B(); }
    }

    public static class Test
    {
        static void doSomething(IA a)
        {
            // a is read-only
        }
        static void alterState(writable.IB b)
        {
            // b is writable
        }
        static void example()
        {
            // Write protected
            IA a = access.A.writeProtected();
            IB b = access.B.writeProtected();

            // write enabled
            writable.IA A = access.A.writable();
            writable.IB B = access.B.writable();

            Console.WriteLine(a.get_a());
            B.set_b(68);

            doSomething(A); // passed as writeprotected
            alterState(B); // passed as writable
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use properties? You can specify access for each `get` and `set` individually. I also remember that List<> has a AsReadOnly(). Maybe it's similar, but it would have to be called from a writable class. BTW, what's the reason for the clear separation of classes?

Comment: how can we define the ReadOnly/Writable versions of a class separately and also support inheritance without it getting very, very, messy? -- You should just create two interfaces(for write and read access) and inherit them from the one class, then create a fabrica where you will choose the needed version of your class. Fabrica will return instance of the class through the needed interface. that is all.

Comment: @GMMan Does using get set properties preclude the use of xml serialisation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28VS.85%29.aspx?

Comment: @GMMan The reason for the separation of read write access is because there are many algorithms which only need to read the values of a class and do not need to make changes. Some algorithms can be written in a more efficient way if it is know that the object state will not change. E.g. During multi-threading the need for locks at certain times can be discarded.

Comment: @Eugene could you expand on what you mean with an example? Thanks.

Comment: Update: I think that this is what Eugene is talking about. -- You are quite right, but I don't know why you want to split interfaces by write/read namespaces.

Comment: @Eugene I want to be able to have interfaces with the same name but with different access levels. I can't put them into the same namespace because they have the same name. Just for hypothetical example, say I want to make IFile to do custom file i/o stuff. I want to be able to pass into some functions a version which is read only and into others a version which is write enabled. So I write:  writeProtected.IFile and writeEnabled.IFile to distinguish but implement in the same class. Otherwise I have to say: IWriteEnabledFile and IWriteProtectedFile which is not as clean.

Comment: ok, it is just kind of tastes. I'm glad that I could help you

Comment: @Eugene, thanks. It is good to discuss a problem and try to explain it to somebody and then they say a few keywords which triggers a better line of thought, otherwise one can get stuck in the same bad line of reasoning - a bit like playing chess.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is one year old, but I'm wondering if it would make sense to have something like this:

```
 interface ReadOnlyA
 {
    object A { get; }
 }

 interface WriteableA : ReadOnlyA
 {
   new object A {get; set;}
 }
```

Comment: You give someone a `WriteableA` instance disguised as `ReadOnlyA`. And they just cast it to `WriteableA` and modify it.

Comment: Well, it depends. If you actually control the writing access, most likely the WriteableA interface will be internal, and only the ReadOnlyA interface will be public, so no casting.

Comment: There is also a library scenario when both `ReadOnlyA` and `WriteableA` are available to external devs. This is common for collections. P.S. Found this question while searching for duplicates to my similar question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216616/an-object-that-securely-provides-both-public-api-read-only-and-private-api-re/

Comment: I see your point; I had the same issue back in time as I wanted to provide an "option panel" where the option model could be readable by every developer anywhere in the app, but the option model could be modified only via Option panel GUI. This way, using internal modifier I could achieve my goal, but it looks like it's different from your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the read/write access at Service level and not at Entity level. In that case you can **code generate** a wrapper around services that handles the read/write access.
Patterns used: Decorator, Dependency Injection

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I think you comment is a suggestion though and not an answer. Ought to placed as a comment rather than an answer? Anyhow, what do you think of the code I put up before your comment on the bottom of the posting? Is it kind of what you are suggesting? If not then could you provide an example code to implement the interfaces? Thanks.